# Why can't I see the submenu from links that are left to the one I selected?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menubar, submenu

I suppose this one might be easy for you css gurus :)
I am trying to apply some css to a page that I am currently working on where I want to have a dropline menu.
I got the code from [here](http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/css-nav-menus/css-drop-line-menu.php) and just did minor modifications (width of the outer ul, class instead of id for the outer ul and z-index instead of huge negative indentation)

As I see there is some misunderstanding, here is some more detail about how this menu should work:

- There are two levels, one on the top and the other underneath.
- The currently selected link from the top menu will have the css-class "current" attached to the li-element that contains that link. (I use the MVC SiteMapProvider for that, but this should not matter for this question)
- **The submenu that is associated with that "current" top menu should be displayed by default,**
- **but it should be overlapped by another submenu if the user hovers over the link to another top menu.**

(hope that clarifies it a bit)

This is the markup I am using:

```
<ul class="mainMenu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
      <a href="#">Sub1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
      <a href="#">Sub1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
      <a href="#">Sub1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="current">
    <a href="#">Link2</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
      <a href="#">Sub2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
      <a href="#">Sub2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
      <a href="#">Sub2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link3</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
      <a href="#">Sub3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
      <a href="#">Sub3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
      <a href="#">Sub3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and it uses these styles:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.mainMenu {
    list-style:none;
    height:3.8em;
    position:relative;
    line-height:1.4em;
}
.mainMenu li {
    width:136px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
.mainMenu a {
    height:1.5em;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    background:#999;
}
.mainMenu li.current ul li.current a, .mainMenu li.current a div, .mainMenu a:active, .mainMenu a:focus, .mainMenu a:hover {
    background:#777;
}
/* --------- Sub Nav --------- */
.mainMenu li.current ul {
    left:0;
}
.mainMenu ul {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    width:408px;
    list-style:none;
    padding:.9em 0 0;
}
.mainMenu ul li {
    width:auto;
    margin:0 15px 0 0;
}
.mainMenu ul a {
    font-size:80%;
    height:auto;
    padding:0 8px;
}
.mainMenu li.current ul, .mainMenu li:hover ul { 
    z-index: 10;

    background:#fff;
}
```

See also [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jKahy/2/) for a fiddle that includes both already.
In general this seems to work pretty well, BUT when I hover to the right (i.e. Link1) I cannot see the corresponding links from the submenu though it works when I hover to the right (i.e. Link3). Anyone got an idea why this is the case?

ps: I also do not know why the current node is not applying the style from

```
.mainMenu li.current ul
```

(at least I do not see it in firefox 17.0.1, though, when not in the fiddle itself I do not have that problem, so probably a minor issue and not my main question here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a bit of CSS :

```
.mainMenu ul {
    display: none;
}

.mainMenu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jKahy/4/)

**EDIT**

Just change or remove `z-index` in `.mainMenu li.current:hover ul`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jKahy/15/)

Comment: this looks a bit better, but now the submenus only display when I hover the main links, I also want to have the submenu of the currently selected main link to display by default and that should be overlapped by another submenu if another link was hovered

Comment: well, almost, but no :) the result looks exactly as the one I originally posted, I cannot hover over Link1 and see its submenu

Comment: ah I got it! just slightly modified your last fiddle and split the rule for .mainMenu li.current ul, .mainMenu li:hover ul into two rules one with z-index 1 for the current and one for the other with 10, if you like you could edit your post and I will accept your answer as you helped me the most here ;)

Comment: lol almost same time :) edit your answer and I will accept it, thanks by the way ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have set `class="active"` to second sub menu so the first menu is under (due to `z-index` set) the second menu. Add active class to first menu

```
<ul class="mainMenu">
          <li class="current">
            <a href="#">Link1</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jKahy/3/)

Comment: that does not solve it, I explicitly set the current class to the second li, BECAUSE I wanted to know how it behaves when the second link is clicked and you hover to the left

Answer (score 0):

You miss place current class i.e. in second menu(LINK2). Remove it and place at first link(LINK1) as below

```
<li class="current">
   <a href="#">Link1</a>.......
</li>
<li> <a href="#">Link2</a> </li>
```